# log4j2 configuration file is confusing

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I have a log4j2 config file I was handed and have no clue what half of it means due to that it doesn't follow what is stated on their site about their configuration file layout. Can anybody decipher what the config file is saying?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="ERROR_FILE" fileName="${env:ADSSSDIR}/log/error.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <File name="EVENT_FILE" fileName="${env:ADSSSDIR}/log/event.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="mikros.utils.MikrosLoggerTest" level="trace"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>       
        <Logger name="mikros.adsss.logger.AdsssLogger" level="debug"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR_FILE" level="ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="EVENT_FILE" level="INFO"/>
        </Logger>       
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config file looks fine to me. Are you looking at the right web site?

User manual links:

- [Status Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages) (showing internal Log4j2 WARN-level messages)
- [monitorInterval](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration)
- [Console Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender)
- [Pattern Layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)
- [File Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender)
- [Environment Variable Lookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup)
- [Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Loggers)
- [additivity](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity)

... That should get you started.

Comment: thanks, I guess I kept running into log4j configs by accident even though I tried log4j2.